# NoFlo async components and data races

Tags: asynchronous, noflo

In NoFlo I often come across components like this:

```
noflo = require 'noflo'

class Foo extends noflo.AsyncComponent
  constructor: ->
    @inPorts = new noflo.InPorts
      main:
        datatype: 'int'
        description: 'Main async input'
        required: true
      sup1:
        datatype: 'string'
        description: 'Supplementary input #1'
        required: true
      sup2:
        datatype: 'int'
        description: 'Supplementary input #2'
        required: true
    @outPorts = new noflo.OutPorts
      out:
        datatype: 'object'
        description: 'Result object'
      error:
        datatype: 'object'

    @sup1 = null
    @sup2 = null

    @inPorts.sup1.on 'data', (@sup1) =>
    @inPorts.sup2.on 'data', (@sup2) =>

    super 'main', 'out'

  doAsync: (main, callback) ->
    unless @sup1 and @sup2
      return callback new Error "Supplementary data missing"

    # Combine data received from different sources
    result =
      main: main
      sup1: @sup1
      sup2: @sup2

    # Reset state until next iteration
    @sup1 = null
    @sup2 = null

    # Send the result
    @outPorts.out.send result
    @outPorts.out.disconnect()

    callback()

exports.getComponent = -> new Foo
```

It assumes that all 3 input connections are synchronized somehow despite the fact that network consists mostly of async components. Consider this situation: `Foo` waits for `main` to come and receives `sup1` and `sup2` packets, but then next `sup1` packet arrives which should be combined with next `main`, while still waiting for previous `main` to come. The result will be a complete mess on more or high data throughput.

Do NoFlo async components have any means of data races protection or it is all up to component designers?

There are 2 sides of the problem here: synchronizing inputs and maintaining internal state. Internal state is more or less protected here by that fact Node.js is not multithreaded and nothing will try to access state variables until previous `doAsync()` handler finishes. But syncing inputs is still a question.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out for NoFlo v0.5.1, there are no built-in aids against data races and component designers have to care about it themselves.

For asynchronous components that means:

1. If data from multiple inports is required, make sure it arrives from all the ports before processing. See [Components & Ports toolbox](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/issues/166).
2. Reset component's state from iteration to iteration to ensure no "memory" side effects take place.
3. Protect component's internal state from a data race by preceding it with a Throttle component and connecting component's LOAD outport with Throttle's LOAD inport.

Answer (score 0):

With recent version of NoFlo, the recommended way is to use noflo.helpers.WirePattern, and syncronize using groups.